# 'DOMException: Failed to construct WebSocket' error in infinite loop

Tags: websocket, https

I have deployed my application and it seems to be stuck in an infinite loop showing the 'insecure websocket' message in the screenshot.

I read on another post that ws:// needs to be set to wss:// but I've no idea where this JS code in the other screen shot exists in the project..

This is a .Net core MVC application

[image: Console output]

[image]